# when click on a link on a page, the Java Servlet Filter is getting called for the clicked link follow by the current page link

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

I have a JSF 3.0 webapp that has a standard Log Out link on the top right corner of every web page.  The link has href="logOut.jsf".  This link calls a backend jsf bean that invalidates the session and forward the request to login.jsp.  The forward code looks like below:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("login.jsp");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setRendered(false);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

This webapp has a servlet filter where it logs all requests that are intercepted by the filter.  Below is what the log looks like when I clicked the Log Out link. Please note that for this log, I clicked it when I was on the accountSelection.jsf page:

The 1st first entry is the accountSelection.jsf page, which is expected.

The 2nd entry is for the click of the Log Out link, logOut.jsf, which is also expected.

The 3rd is the accountSelection.jsf again, which is NOT expected.

Since the "logOut.jsf" does a forward to login.jsp, I am expecting the 3rd request to be login.jsp.  But for some reasons it comes into the filter as accountSelection.jsf.   This is causing issue because this filter has logic to check if session has expired and handle it accordingly.  Since the logOut.jsf has invalidated the session and the request is not the login.jsp page, it causes the filter to execute the  session expired condition.

```
02/28-14:54 SessionExpiredFilter-isContinueTheChain() - /MyAccount/accountSelection.jsf
02/28-14:55 SessionExpiredFilter-isContinueTheChain() - /MyAccount/logOut.jsf
02/28-14:55 SessionExpiredFilter-isContinueTheChain() - /MyAccount/accountSelection.jsf
02/28-14:55 SessionExpiredFilter-isContinueTheChain() - Session Time Out caught by SessionExpiredFilter (ViewID=)/accountSelection.jsf) - Redirecting user to errorpage_viewexpired.jsp.
```

Comment: This question is not answerable based on the information provided so far. You forgot to debug and break down the HTTP requests yourself. We're not in a position to do this because you didn't provide any [mcve]. Press F12 in webbrowser to open the developer tools and then check the *Network* tab therein. The cause of the problem is by the way completely unrelated to servlet filters. It's in the context of this problem basically just a messenger, not a possible cause.

Comment: I just realized that the logOut.jsf does a forward to login.jsp using the jsf ExternalContext: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("login.jsp");  So, the 3rd request could be caused by this forward.  I just need to figure out why it comes in as /MyAccount/accountSelection.jsf, and not /MyAccount/login.jsp.

Comment: Forward? You should always be sending a redirect after logout. And in JSF, you should be using (implicit) navigation cases instead of manually meddling with ExternalContext. E.g. `return "login?faces-redirect=true";`.